# Mysql restore only data

Tags: php, mysql

Good afternoon,
I have many old backup files (created with mysqldump) that fully backup my database (tables structure, data and procedures).
Now i have to alter a column CHAR(5) to VARCHAR(7) in a table but i want that my old backups are compatible with new structure. Can I restore only data from these old backup?
For the future I have already changed my php script to backup only data with --no-crete-info option in mysqldump.

Thanks a lot
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you upload the mysql dump to PhpMyAdmin then change the column from CHAR(5) to VARCHAR(7) using the edit Structure tab. This would seem to be your easiest option if you aren't too sure how to edit the file dump.

Comment: I haven't PhpMyAdmin. I create my database with script. I have already modified the .sql script but if I restore an old backup the actual table column VARCHAR(7) is overridden with CHAR(5)

Answer (score 0):

The best way of handling this data definition change is to do it in place.

1. make a backup before the change.
2. take your application offline, so nobody's trying to hit the database.
3. Issue the command `ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn VARCHAR(5);`

Then you'll be up and running. You can start your application again, and you can take another backup. Finally you *may* want to issue this command.

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn = TRIM(mycolumn)
```

to deal with potential trailing spaces in your old column values.